# How to prove there is left\right adjoint for non-degenerate bilinear form?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form, adjoint-operators

Let $V$ and $W$ be $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces such that $dim(V) =dim(W)<∞$.  Let $φ$ be a non-degenerate bilinear form on $V×W$.
Show that: for every $f∈L(V)$, there exists $g\in L(W)$ such that $φ(f(v),w) =φ(v,g(w))$,  $v∈V,w∈W$.
This is the right adjoint of $f$ and similarly, there is a left adjoint.
I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ be bases for $V$ and $W$ (respectively). We want to define a linear map $g:W \to W$ by selecting vectors $g(w_j)$ so that for all $i$ and $j$, we have
$$
\varphi(v_i,g(w_j)) = \varphi(f(v_i),w_j)
$$
Having done this, we can extend $g$ to all of $W$ by linearity.

That is, for each $j = 1,\dots,n$, we wish to find vectors $g(w_j)$ which solve the linear system
$$
\pmatrix{
\varphi(v_1,g(w_j))\\
\varphi(v_2,g(w_j))\\ 
\vdots\\
\varphi(v_n,g(w_j))
} = 
\pmatrix{
\varphi(f(v_1),w_j)\\
\varphi(f(v_2),w_j)\\ 
\vdots\\
\varphi(f(v_n),w_j)
}
$$

Using the fact that our bilinear form is non-degenerate, why is it necessarily possible to find such vectors $g(w_j)$?

---

**Hint 2:** Show that because $\varphi$ is non-degenerate, the linear map 
$$
\Phi(x) = \pmatrix{
\varphi(v_1,x)\\
\varphi(v_2,x)\\ 
\vdots\\
\varphi(v_n,x)
}
$$
is invertible.

Comment: Sorry can you add more? It still sounds difficult for me. I don't know how to use "non-degenerate". It seems like we need to use a stronger version of Riesz Representation theorem?

Comment: @EricSun see my latest edit